# How can I make a popup message window when the timer countdown over in java?

Tags: java, javafx

When I was trying to implement popups, I did something like this:

Code snippet in OptionController:

```
static int SECOND = 100;

Timer timer = new Timer();
  TimerTask task =
      new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

          SECOND--;

          if (SECOND == 0) {
            timer.cancel();

            try {
              AlertController.courtChangeAlert("Time's up."); // line 56
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
      };

public void clickTimerStart() throws IOException {
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Code snippet in AlertController:

```
public static void courtChangeAlert(String alert) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader =
        new FXMLLoader(AlertController.class.getResource("/view/CourtChangeAlert.fxml"));
    showScene(fxmlLoader, alert); // line 43
  }

private static void showScene(FXMLLoader fxmlLoader, String alert) throws IOException {
    AnchorPane alertPane = fxmlLoader.load();
    AlertController alertController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    alertController.setAlertLabel(alert);
    Scene scene = new Scene(alertPane);
    Stage stage = new Stage();  // line 51
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
```

After the countdown ends, I got error message:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-0
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:241)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:227)
    at controller.AlertController.showScene(AlertController.java:51)
    at controller.AlertController.courtChangeAlert(AlertController.java:43)
    at controller.OptionController$1.run(OptionController.java:56)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I modify the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the line `AlertController.courtChangeAlert("Time's up.");` so that it is started on the JavaFX thread.

```
Platform.runLater(()->AlertController.courtChangeAlert("Time's up."));
```

The timer has it's own thread, and when it fires the action it fires it on it's own thread and not javafx's thread. That is the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Long stories short, a Timer() starts a new process, which is incapable of popping up your new window. You will need to invoke [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to popup your window in the FX thread. And you will have to wrap your function as a [Runnable()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) in turn.